# Extract date parts from integer

Tags: c++, date

I couldn't find this anywhere but it was useful for me to do, so I thought I'd post it.

Given an integer ISO representation of a date, extract the year/month/day.

Why did I need this? Because we have libraries that use this int representation and converting to/from a boost::gregorian_date was causing a performance issue. Storing as an int everywhere is a smaller structure and seems to be faster (in our particular case).

```
void iso_date_to_parts(const int iso_date) {
    const int year = date / 10000;
    const int month = (date / 100) % 100;
    const int day = date % 100;
}
```

Hopefully someone will find it useful. I don't think there is a more efficient way of doing this (maybe using scanf?)

**Edit**
An iso date representation is 20131204.
The question is "How would I extract the year/month/day parts from this integer representation in the most efficient way"

Use case:
Where day level resolution only is required in code, and boost::gregorian or struct_tm would be space and time inefficient

Comment: Can you show an example of an `iso_date` integer?

Comment: A proposal for representing date/time

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: 20131204 (representing 4th December 2013)

Comment: We've been using that exact date format for years, and our algorithm is pretty much exactly the code you posted. The only way to optimize it is to reduce the number of divides (but that increases the total number of operations), which I would post in an answer had people not put this thing on hold because the [**actual** definition of "ISO format"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is with dashes: 2013-12-04.

Comment: P.S. If you really absolutely cared about speed, you'd store it as a bitfield. Year is 7 bits (epoch 1980), month is four bits, and day is five bits. Fits in a `uint16_t` and requires absolutely no multiplies or divides to encode or decode. Incidentally, [this is what the FAT filesystem uses.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Format_Date)